# Setting custom date for cordova-date-picker plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am facing issue with setting custom date for the cordova date picker plugin [cordova-plugin-datepicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) in my cordova project. but it is showing only current date.

ex:

```
var options = {
            date: new Date('12/12/2015'),
            mode: 'datetime', // or 'time'
            minDate :  moment().subtract(100, 'years').toDate(),
            allowOldDates: true,
            allowFutureDates: true,
            androidTheme : 2,
            doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
            doneButtonColor: '#000000',
            cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
            cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
      };

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {  

            $cordovaDatePicker.show(options)
            .then(function(date){

                $scope.appointmentVM.dateFrom = new Date(date).valueOf().toString();

            });

      });
```

Here you can see `new Date('12/12/2015')` is set but it will show current date in the picker instead of set date.

Could you please help.

**Updated:**
I got the solution :

we have to set the minDate as below in the date options. will solve the issue

```
minDate : ionic.Platform.isIOS() ? moment().subtract(100,'years').toDate() : moment().subtract(100,'years').valueOf(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug using only `date` and `mode` options.

```
var options = {
    date: new Date('12/12/2015'),
    mode: 'datetime'
};
```

Also try with a less old `minDate` option.

Comment: The link which you provided is different issue. Mine is not able to set different date. even it is not working in both android and ios

Comment: Have you tried passing only the `mode` and the `date` option to simplify the debug?

Comment: Hey, actually you are right. after providing only mode and date i was able to set. Actaully the issue is with minDate. if i provide that it will not work. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried using a less old minDate? E.g. one year ago

Comment: Hey its working I have updated my question with the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'll update my answer, accept if you think it was useful.